# golang: how to detach current process from console inside itself (programatically)?

Tags: linux, go, console

I wrote a service program in Go, let's say, a web server.  I run it like this:

```
mywebsvr &
```

How can I make the program detach itself from console without having to start it with `&`. In Windows, I can do:

```
    k32 := syscall.NewLazyDLL("kernel32.dll")
    freeConsole := k32.NewProc("FreeConsole")
    freeConsole.Call()
```

How to do this under linux?

Comment: Please give a read to the proposal [runtime: support for daemonize](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/227) which was rejected.